# Caman image manipulation and flickering

Tags: javascript, image-processing, camanjs

I'm using the Caman (http://camanjs.com/) image library to modify some images using buttons/sliders.  The problem is, that the image flickers each time a change is made.

Example code:

```
    var caman = Caman("#demo-photo");
    $("#contrast-btn").click(function() {
      caman.revert(false);
      caman.contrast(50).render();
    });
```

According to the docs, `caman.revert(false)` should revert the image without re-rendering, but what I see is the image revert for maybe 0.1sec, before the effect is applied again.

Tested on both Chrome and Firefox.  Is this a bug in Caman (or the browsers) and is there a workaround, or does anyone have other ideas?

The examples on the website (http://camanjs.com/examples/) don't flicker, but the JS is minified and hard to follow so I'm not sure what is going on.

thanks!

Comment: FYI, there are de-minifiers available.

Comment: DeMinifiers aren't great - they can't give functions/variables useful names again for example - but I was pointed to the site source in Github - https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS-Site/blob/master/_assets/javascripts/examples.js.coffee

Unfortunately it's in CoffeeScript!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved [here](https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/issues/130).

Updating to caman to 4.1.2 solved the problem.

Comment: Dunno what was "resolved" but I'm in the latest bleeding edge release, and when I do `revert(false)` it's not reverting the canvas to the original image (it's applying my functions to the image that is in canvas - that was already processed on a previous call), but when I do `revert(true)` it's flickering.